# Use glade with pygobject Gtk3

Tags: pygtk, glade, pygobject, gtk3

I am converting a script to use Gtk3 using the migration guide ([Porting GTK2 to GTK3](http://live.gnome.org/PyGObject/IntrospectionPorting#Porting_from_PyGTK_2_to_PyGI_GTK_3)). I converted my `import pygtk` to a `from gi.repository import Gtk` and so on...

I'm stuck because the glade module was loaded from module gtk:

```
 import gtk
 import gtk.glade
```

but there's no way now to do that anymore.

Note that I would only need a replacement for `gtk.glade.XML()`...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, the solution is pretty obvious, after calling to `Gtk.Builder()` one needs to convert the old glade interface with the `gtk-builder-convert` command to get the interface file in the right version.

```
 $ gtk-builder-convert myui.glade myui.ui
```

And then, in the python script:

```
 from gi.repository import Gtk
 builder = Gtk.Builder()
 builder.add_from_file("myui.ui")
```

Thanks to Riccardo.

Answer (score 4):

This should work

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("project.xml")
```

Comment: Well, I get called names by Python, because my XML file has a non-valid root element called `glade-interface` :)

Comment: I get the same issue. We really need some simple tutorials on using Glade and PYGObject, if thas what they want us to use. Too much reliance on PyGTK at the moment.

Comment: did it work? I couldn't test it. In that case I'll change the wording to "This works"

Comment: nop it didn't, see my first comment. What form does project.xml must have ? Isn't it a glade file ?

Comment: as far I remember, time ago libglade was superseded by gtk.builder to have an official gtk api. The format must have changed. See http://www.micahcarrick.com/gtk-builder-libglade-faq.html